# Xamarin Droid YouTube API - Get Video Metadata

Tags: android, api, xamarin, youtube

I'm working on a Xamarin project that uses YouTube API v3. I'm able to play videos but I want to display separately some metadata like view's counter, video name and publishing time. Is there any way to get this information?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use YouTube API v3 itself, take a look at the [Videos Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos). The resource returns a JSON blob, and you'll find the view count under [`statistics.viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics).

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at YouTubeApi for Xamarin.